# Modus ponens proof

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, formal-proofs

I'm trying to prove that $\neg\bullet\varphi$ in system $L(\neg, \to, \bullet)$,

$\bullet \varphi \approx (\varphi \to \varphi)$

Axiomas are the followind:

A1) $\neg\neg\bullet\bullet\varphi$

A2) $(\neg\bullet\varphi \to \neg \psi)$

A3) $((\varphi\to\psi) \to (\neg\psi\to\neg\varphi))$

but still with no success. Could anybody suggest me some flow of proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We cannot prove it ...

As said in your previous [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1002707/modus-ponens-proof-in-system-l%c2%ac-%e2%86%92-%e2%88%99) :

> in system $\mathcal L(\neg, \to, \bullet)$, $\bullet$ "acts" as a constant truth, i.e. $\bullet \varphi \approx (\varphi \to \varphi)$.

If we consider the usual truth functional properties of the conncetives : $\lnot, \rightarrow$, and replace $\bullet \varphi$ with $\top$ ("the *true*"), we have that :

> A1) $\neg\neg\bullet\bullet\varphi$ is $\neg \neg (\top \to \top)$, that is always $\top$
>
> A2) $(\neg\bullet\varphi \to \neg \psi)$ is $(\neg \top \to \neg \psi)$, that is $(\bot \to \neg \psi)$, and again it is always $\top$
>
> A3) $((\varphi\to\psi) \to (\neg\psi\to\neg\varphi))$ is a *tautology*; thus it is also $\top$.

Of course, *modus ponens* preserves validity.

But :

> > $\neg\bullet\varphi$ is $\neg \top$ i.e. $\bot$.